# Static 404 pages with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all 404 errors to a static html page. This should be done outside of WordPress via .htaccess so it doesn't use any WordPress resources. The standard WordPress mod_rewrite rules are as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried adding ErrorDocument 404 /static.html to the top of the .htaccess file, but no luck. How can I catch 404 errors and redirect to static.html?

Comment: Did you find a solution this that answers the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option I found was to place the following in .htaccess:

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404

It will load a 404.php page found in your theme directory.

Comment: This is actually the opposite of what was asked. Not using 404.php from the theme directory but instead use a static file outside of wordpress

Comment: This does not look like a solution to the question asked. The question specifically asked to have a 404 static page _outside_ of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your htaccess,

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: See comment above. I tried adding ErrorDocument 404 /static.html to the top of the .htaccess file, but no luck.

Comment: try it without slash and remove any other wordpress ot htaccess rule related to this.